# How do you run bash script as a command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script, which I use for configuration of different parameters in text files in my wireless access media server.

The script is located in one directory, and because I do all of configurations using putty, I have to either use the full path of the file or move to the directory that contains the file. I would like to avoid this.

Is it possible to save the bash script in or edit the bash script so that I can run it as command, for example as `cp` or `ls` commands?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The script needs to be executable, with:

```
chmod +x scriptname
```

(or similar).

Also, you want the script to be located in a directory that is in your PATH.
To see your PATH use:

```
echo $PATH
```

Your choices are: to move (or link) the file into one of those directories, or to add the directory it is in to your PATH.

You can add a directory to your PATH with:

```
PATH=$PATH:/name/of/my/directory
```

and if you do this in the file `$HOME/.bashrc` it will happen for each of your shell's automatically.

Comment: I can run script, my question is: can I and how can I create a bash script that I can use as a command. For example instead of typing `/media/data/script.sh` can I configure linux to type just `script`

Comment: That's what the PATH environment variable is -- a list of directories to search for commands in.  You can change your PATH in the file `.bashrc` in your home dir.

Comment: A shell alias as suggested by @Andy K  is another option.

Answer (score 5):

You can place a softlink to the script under /usr/local/bin (Should be in $PATH like John said)

```
ln -s /path/to/script /usr/local/bin/scriptname
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Users don't normally have write permission to `/usr/local/bin`.  I'd recommend `$HOME/bin`, and add it to the `$PATH` in `.profile` or `.bashrc` as appropriate.

Comment: Thats of course assuming that the user has sufficent rights. Most times I use this approach because other users of the system are also able to use the command then (in case you want that). But for a user with not sufficent rights I fully agree with you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a minimal wrapper in your home directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /yourpath/yourfile.extension
```

And run your child script with this command `./NameOfYourScript`

**update**: Unix hawks will probably say the first solution is a no-brainer because of the additional admin work it will load on you. Agreed, but on your requirements, my solution works :)

Otherwise, you can use an alias; you will have to amend your `.bashrc`

```
alias menu='bash /yourpath/menuScript.sh'
```

Comment: @TobySpeight - true, but that concern is out of scope for an answer here, since the question didn't include the script.

Comment: ok @TobySpeight mate you got me. Thanks for http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=turd+polishing ;)

Comment: This alias solution was what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to run it with:

```
/bin/bash /path/to/script
```

Then the file doesn't need to be executable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script as below

```
#!/bin/bash
Shell script to run
```

Export the script Path in to a variable:

```
export script="/path/to/script"
```

Type **"Script"** Command in the CLI to Get Shell script Executed

```
# script
```

If you want to make sure Script command should run in different sessions add below in **.bashrc** file

```
export Script="/path/to/script"
```